# accessing third-party websites repeatedly efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have to collect the twitter statuses of 100,000+ users daily. Like access twitter for each user. I was wondering what the most efficient way of doing using PHP and mysql (I'm using the Yii PHP framework)? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, or what ideas have you rejected because they are "inefficient?"

Comment: You'd better ask Twitter for permission... they're not going to like you banging on their server 100,000 times a day, for days/weeks/months on-end: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Yii cache functions: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data there are many approaches, disk, mysql, redis, etc., the best one for you depends on your set-up, but certainly some kind of cache strategy is advised when fetching 3rd-party data.

Comment: I was planning to run a cron job to access the users' twitter data. I was planning to run that cron job at 1am every day, but I'm guessing that's a big load on the server. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of data you are getting and if you need to do any processing on that data, etc. If it's an issue of getting some user-specific data to display to a user, you may want to wait until they request it and then cache it for a certain amount of time, which spreads the load around and only refreshes the users who need it. You could still do the cron job if you need all the data and then refresh a specific users data on demand (+cache) if needed.

Comment: I am processing the data. Like measuring how many statuses they do a minute, and what is the percentage change in number of statuses for a specific amount of time like a month, etc. so yes I'm doing calculations on the data. thanks!